# LWC - Is there anyway I can push value from 2 @wire into 1 array

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lightning-combobox, wire

I have `2 @wire Apex methods` that will invoke code from Apex Controller. Right now the array `only has value from the 1st wire (because it get called first) but not the 2nd one`.

My question is: ***How can I have 1 array with result from 2 wire***.

HTML code:

```
<lightning-combobox required name="fieldList" label="Group By" onchange={handleGetPicklistFieldsOptions} options={lstOfSummarizedFields}
</lightning-combobox>
```

JS code:

```
@track lstOfSummarizedFields = [];
    wireAllCurrencyRes = ''
    @wire(getCurrencyTypeFields,{ strObjectName : '$sObjectType' })
    wireAllCurrency(result) {
        this.wireAllCurrencyRes = result;
        let {error, data} = result;
        if(data) {
            for (let key in data) {
                this.lstOfSummarizedFields.push({ label: key, value: data[key] });
            }
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log('Error in getting currency fields');
        }
    }

    wireAllNumberRes = ''
    @wire(getNumberFields,{ strObjectName : '$sObjectType' })
    wireAllNumber(result) {
        this.wireAllNumberRes = result;
        let {error, data} = result;
        if(data) {
            for (let key in data) {
                this.lstOfSummarizedFields.push({ label: key, value: data[key] });
            }
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log('Error in getting number fields');
        }
    }
```

- I tried to create a new array to push 2 results into one but it does not work as well.

HTML code:

```
<lightning-combobox required name="fieldList" label="Group By" onchange={handleGetPicklistFieldsOptions} options={lstOfAllFields}
</lightning-combobox>
```

JS code:

```
@track lstOfAllFields = [];
@track lstOfSummarizedFields = [];
    wireAllCurrencyRes = ''
    @wire(getCurrencyTypeFields,{ strObjectName : '$sObjectType' })
    wireAllCurrency(result) {
        this.wireAllCurrencyRes = result;
        let {error, data} = result;
        if(data) {
            for (let key in data) {
                this.lstOfSummarizedFields.push({ label: key, value: data[key] });
                this.lstOfAllFields.push(this.lstOfSummarizedFields)//push this into an 
            }
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log('Error in getting currency fields');
        }
    }

    wireAllNumberRes = ''
    @wire(getNumberFields,{ strObjectName : '$sObjectType' })
    wireAllNumber(result) {
        this.wireAllNumberRes = result;
        let {error, data} = result;
        if(data) {
            for (let key in data) {
                this.lstOfAllFields.push({ label: key, value: data[key] });
            }
        }
        if(error) {
            console.log('Error in getting number fields');
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With push, you're putting the entire array into an element of another array, rather than concatenating the values. In addition, you're calling that in a loop, which means lots of duplicate values. Either way should be considered incorrect, since you're never clearing the values. This would matter if sObjectType changed; you'd have a list of the old and new values. Instead, consider:

```
lstOfAllFields = [];
lstOfSummarizedFields = [];
wireAllCurrencyRes = {};
wireAllNumberRes = {};
@wire(getCurrencyTypeFields, { strObjectName: "$sObjectType" })
wireAllCurrency(result) {
  this.wireAllCurrencyRes = result;
  this.updateLists();
}
@wire(getNumberFields, { strObjectName: "$sObjectType" })
wireAllNumber(result) {
  this.wireAllNumberRes = result;
  this.updateLists();
}
updateLists() {
  this.lstOfSummarizedFields = [];
  this.lstOfAllFields = [];
  if (this.wireAllCurrencyRes.data) {
    this.lstOfSummarizedFields = Object.entries(
      this.wireAllCurrencyRes.data
    ).map(([label, value]) => ({ label, value }));
    // copy array
    this.lstOfAllFields = [...this.lstOfSummarizedFields];
  }
  if (this.wireAllNumberRes.data) {
    this.lstOfAllFields = [
      ...this.lstOfAllFields, // Copy any values
      ...Object.entries(this.wireAllNumberRes.data).map(([label, value]) => ({
        label,
        value,
      })),
    ];
  }
}
```

You'll want to take a look at Arrow functions, destructuring statements, Object.entries, and shorthand object notation if you'd like to understand more about how they work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'll take a look at your recommendations.